# Angular leaflet icons are not replacing each other but overlapping instead

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

On my ngOnInit im initializing a few things, such as the markers on my map. Initially they are all initialized with the same icon. Whenever I select a marker, I want it to change to the "selected icon". The problem here however is that my program isnt replacing the old icon with a new one. Instead its just adding the icon on top of the current icon, and whenever I select a second marker, and try to clear my recent selected marker, nothing happen (since the two icons just are overlapping).

```
vehicleDetails: VehicleDetail[]; //array contains a bunch of VehicleDetail's.

 // markers with vehicle IDs
markerAdv = Leaflet.Marker.extend({
    options: {
      vehicleId: ''
    }
  });
markers = new this.markerAdv();


  // Set the icons across the map.
  setMarkers(id: number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vehicleDetails.length; i++) {
        // Creating the markers
        this.markers = new this.markerAdv(
          [
            this.vehicleDetails[i].position.latitude,
            this.vehicleDetails[i].position.longitude
          ],
          {
            icon: this.myBlueIcon,
            vehicleId: this.vehicleDetails[i].id
          }
        )
          .addTo(this.map)
          .bindPopup(`${this.vehicleDetails[i].name} : ${status}  `)
          .on('mouseover', function(e) {
            this.openPopup();
          })
          .on('mouseout', function(e) {
            this.closePopup();
          })
          .on(
            'click',
            function(event) {
              this.updateInfo(event.target.options.vehicleId);
            },
            this
          );
        // Highlighting the marked vehicle
        if (id === this.vehicleDetails[i].id) {
          this.markers.setIcon(this.myBlueSelectedIcon);
        } else {
          this.markers.setIcon(this.myRedIcon);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What can I do to avoid this overlapping problem and instead replace the icon whenever it is selected/being cleared?

Comment: You have to keep track of your markers in order to delete them. I Suggest you use a `Map` (an indexed array) so that it becomes easier to find the markers.

Comment: Alright. Do you have a link for the documentation of map? I havent been able to find it. Or is it a part of the javascript library? Would it work to add a "select" option to the marker, and set it to 0/1 depending on if it is selected or not?

Comment: This is part of typescript, maybe Javascript. It's pretty straightforward, it behaves like the local storage, create a new Map, and use `get/set` to manage it.

Comment: @trichetriche So ive been trying to fix this map but its just not working. Everytime I try to add the marker in the following way:

        this.allMarkers.set(this.markers.options.vehicleId, this.markers);

 I get a "Cannot read property 'set' of null" in every case, even if I know the marker exist. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you, write `allMarkers = new Map()` ? You have to instantiate it, not only declare it. And apparently you set it to null somewhere, you should remove that too.

Comment: Ahhh I just type declared it into a map. It works like a charm now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments : when you append markers to a leaflet map, it only appends them : it **does not** remove them.

If you want to remove them, you have to do it manually.

This is done by tracking your markers, and deleting them on command.

The best tracker (when you have something to ID your markers), is to use a `Map` :

```
markers: Map<number, Leaflet.Marker> = new Map();
```